# Problemas com o ngModel required na diretiva

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um problema na minha diretiva, ela recebe um `ngModel` para nele inserir um valor que há em um campo de texto dentro dela, mas quando esse model já vem com algum valor ela simplesmente desaparece com ele.

Basicamente o que eu quero é passar o `ngModel` para minha diretiva, se houver algum valor no model ela inserir no campo de texto, e qualquer modificação do campo ela modificar no model.

Comment: Coloque o código que esta com problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa de uma diretiva para que isso aconteça.
O AngularJS possui um conceito de Two-way-data-binding. 
Quando você coloca ng-model no seu campo texto e declara a variável com o mesmo nome em seu module, qualquer alteração que você faz de um lado reflete do outro.
Por padrão, para cada elemento declarado com o ng-model na sua view, o angular cria um $scope.$watch() para esse elemento que vigia qualquer alteração nele e reflete do outro lado.